# Why did Trump suddenly flip on the gun issue?

Tags: donald-trump, guns, second-amendment

Trump seems to have suddenly changed his position on guns completely ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/28/us/politics/trump-gun-control.html)).

What is the cause of this sudden change in position? And why now?

> In a meeting with lawmakers, President Trump expressed support for a
>   “comprehensive” gun bill that would include stronger background checks
>   and temporarily take guns away from high-risk individuals.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because you're asking us to speculate over the thought process and OODA loop of Donald Trump, an act that is endlessly subjective without being in his head.

Comment: I have not asked anyone to speculate about anything.

Comment: I would wait for an actual proposal before asking this question. All there is now is talk.

Comment: @user1721135: Yes, you have.  One can only speculate about why anyone does anything, unless they explain their reasons.  And in many cases that just redirects the speculation to whether they're being honest about their motivations.

Comment: This applies to a lot of questions.

Comment: Trump is not exactly consistent in general.

Comment: Ultimately, he has not taken any actual position. He has made statements about gun control, but has not signed any executive orders or proposed legislation, so I am not sure you can say he's changed anything.  He quite often takes multiple positions on issues.

Comment: @user1721135 : this applies to most "why"-questions. Which are most often closed as off-topic...

Answer (score 7):

As multiple Conservative commentators have noted, Trump never really changed his position on guns, he just wasn't as vocal about it as Hillary Clinton was. I mean, the man had stated, multiple times prior to his candidacy, that he was for gun control and never really repudiated that position (which is notable for a candidate who repudiated a LOT of his prior positions). [Case in point](https://www.nationalreview.com/2018/03/trumps-sudden-love-of-gun-control-isnt-that-sudden/) (emphasis mine)

> But Donald Trump, a Manhattan real-estate mogul who had traveled with his own personal security for years, had never really been a “gun guy.” He says he has a concealed carry permit (hard to get in New York state). **In his 2000 book, The America We Deserve, he wrote, “I generally oppose gun control, but I support the ban on assault weapons and I also support a slightly longer waiting period to purchase a gun.”**
>
> The NRA traditionally declined to endorse candidates that supported policies like that, and the group rarely was credulous about conveniently timed changes in position. An endorsement that touted Trump as a longtime defender of the Second Amendment just wouldn’t be accurate. NRA officials Wayne LaPierre and Chris Cox did the best they could, speaking extensively about the menace that Hillary Clinton represented, and then touting Trump as . . . well, not Hillary.
>
> Even in his remarks accepting the endorsement, Trump made comments that suggested he found owning a lot of guns . . . kind of worrisome. “My sons are members,” Trump declared. **“They have so many rifles, so many guns, that even I get concerned. I say, ‘That’s a lot!’”** The crowd greeted that admission with what can best be described as polite silence.

As to why now, we just recently had a [major school shooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoneman_Douglas_High_School_shooting) and the issue is forefront in politics.

Comment: I was thinking about the school shooting too, but wasn't his first reaction to that "let's arm the teachers"?

Comment: @user1721135 Trump is a populist (and sometimes his reasoning is known only to him). At the time, a lot of commentary was suggesting that and I suspect it sounded good to him. But arming teachers is not mutually exclusive of gun control either.